# Python. Sympy. Как посчитать произведение последовательности чисел?

Tags: python, sympy

Допустим, есть последовательность функций cos(x/2^k). Требуется найти произведение этих функций при k от 1 до бесконечности.
Вот есть сумма ряда - тут у sympy все понятно и просто, мне нужен такой же аналог, но для произведения.
Гугл мне ничего вменяемого давать не хочет, по sympy вообще мало информации.
Как посчитать произведение бесконечного функционального ряда?

Comment: В названии опечатка. Там не "чисел", а "функций".

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то вы вот это ищете: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html?highlight=product#sympy.concrete.products.product

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski эта функция (product) не считает даже легкие произведения, а выводит как есть. К примеру, product(exp(-k), (k,1,oo)) -- эту функцию он не считает, хотя тут очевидно 0.